# Twilio with python to repeat voice call until get answered?

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I can make call using twilio programmable call as my [python code here](https://gitlab.com/namgivu/twilio-start/-/tree/try-pause-between-repeat)

The calls sometimes result as `no-answer` or `busy` i.e. the call get rejected or not-answered.

My google search [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=twilio+repeat+voice+call+until+get+answered&oq=twilio+repeat+voice+call+until+get+answered&aqs=chrome..69i57.8595j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and search on our stackoverflow site [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=twilio+repeat+voice+call+until+get+answered+site:stackoverflow.com&newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALeKk01t-P7PUW_hcwOcUJPaPetBxVUxuw:1600486027463&ei=i3plX93sG4HVmAWkxILwAw&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwid3omJo_TrAhWBKqYKHSSiAD4Q8NMDegQIDBBA&biw=1848&bih=976) found little helpful result so I asked here - how to repeat calling until get answered?

p.s.

I'm looking for built-in solution from twilio directly e.g. some TwiML xml tag or attribute for `callUntilAnswered='true'`

Comment: use an if then statement and you can check the status of the call. here is a link that explains how to check that status: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132267-Tracking-the-Status-of-an-Outbound-Twilio-Voice-Call

Comment: Thanks @cbracketdash - I'll have a look.

Comment: That's about `idea` - any working code or built-in from twilio directly may be more helpful. Thanks any way!

Comment: Updated my question to amplify `seek for built-in twilio solution` @cbracketdash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://gitlab.com/namgivu/twilio-start/-/blob/master/quickstart/bin/run_make_call_until_answer.sh) and [here](https://gitlab.com/namgivu/twilio-start/-/blob/master/quickstart/src/make_call_until_answered.py) is how I have to code it manually to get the phone call auto-redial.

The main idea there is to keep pinging the api to get call status and detect busy call (ringing after 60s and no answer); redial when it is busy.

p.s.

To run in background and multiple numbers at the same time, the sample code is [here](https://gitlab.com/namgivu/twilio-start/-/blob/master/quickstart/bin/run_make_call_until_answered__run_in_background.sh)

Answer (score 1):

There is a blog covering this exact use case below using Twilio Studio - log in and visit this [url](https://www.twilio.com/console/studio/dashboard) to open it. There is no built in Twilio capability to retry on your behalf.

[Call Me When You're Free - Using Twilio Studio and Python to Retry a Busy Number](https://www.twilio.com/blog/using-twilio-studio-python-retry-busy-number)

Comment: I cannot find a working right-away from the blog. Can you help adding more detail instruction please?